# Why mysql multiple column index match from left(The Left-Prefix Index Rule)?

Tags: mysql

Why MySQL using union index from left? For example union index(a,b,c),(a) could using index,(a,b) could using index,but (b,c) could not using index!!!Any useful tool to probe MySQL index file structure? How could this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it simple and very clear for understanding without technical details:

```
1,4,1
1,5,1
2,1,4
2,3,1
3,0,2
```

1st column is sorted

2nd column sorted independent for each cluster in 1st column

3rd column sorted for each 1+2 cluster

so, (2,1,x) will always after (1,4,x), but it is not true for (x,4,1) vs (x,1,4)

Comment: is it possible to show the multi column index structure? @a_vlad

Comment: sorry, not very clear, what is your question? (is it still actual after 3.5 year? ) The basic of B-Tree indexes you can find here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree, if you are looking for deep technical details, then you need to check source code of MySQL, some good details here - https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/btree-index-structures-in-innodb/

Comment: I am fimiliar with B+ tree and already read the introducing of B+ tree. I also read the article what you said, I just want to figure this multi colum index left-prefix rule more deeper. @a_vlad